# AppBox - Unable to Install "YourApp" Please try again later

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, appbox

On the macbook I exported a successfully tested app from Xcode 11.4 and dropped the .ipa file in AppBox. Appbox then gives you a link.Then I emailed the link to myself, clicked the link in Safari on my iPhone 7, tapped Install Application and got ‘“dl.dropbox.com” would like to install “News”’. I tapped Install.

It created the News app on the phone, but when I tap, I get "Unable to Install “News” Please try again later.

The I tried Diawi. Same result as AppBox.

Comment: With what profile did you build the app? Did you check if you have to add the iPhone UUID has to be added to the profile? Else you can use developer profile using "Team" in Xcode and use the ipa exported. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Diawi installation link in the browser.
There you can see that provisioning profile section.
Under that section check your iPhone on which you want to install the app it UDID is present or not?